# Unable to access index for repository http://mirrors.dotsrc.org/cran/src/contrib

Tags: r, gplots

I have tried to install the package gplots in R using

```
> install.packages("gplots")
```

However, it returns a warning and an error

```
Advarsel: unable to access index for repository
http://mirrors.dotsrc.org/cran/src/contrib
Advarsel: unable to access index for repository
http://mirrors.dotsrc.org/cran/bin/macosx/mavericks/contrib/3.2
Advarselsbesked:
package ‘gplots’ is not available (for R version 3.2.1)
```

I tried to install another package that should definitely be available (I've installed it before with this version of R) but it also failed with the same warning. Does anyone know why I can't access these repositories?

Comment: Change the mirror using the `repos` argument in `install.packages`. The dotsrc.org mirror seems to be down for almost 2 days (https://cran.r-project.org/mirmon_report.html#dk)

Comment: That's right, thanks :)

Comment: The mirror is now up.